# Getting Different format for same azure location

Tags: java, string, azure, algorithm, sorting

I am getting Azure Resource location in different formats for the same location

```
for example: "India Central" as "In Central" or "Central In" or "Central India"
             "Us West Central" as " West Central US"
```

like this getting all locations in different formats. Due to this unique row is getting created in the database. Now I handled this by keeping a JSON file with all possible location formats but it's not a good way to handle this because need to update a location if any are newly added.
Using Java and Mysql
How can handle this effectively?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CLI command to get all regions and store in your database,

```
az account list-locations -o table
```

use the same format across your application

Comment: This will give me a list of locations but it will be difficult in mapping a location with resources because at resource level I will get different location formats so mapping this is the problem

Comment: What do you mean by mapping with resource? where does it comes from? you may suggest to pull the location from this list

Comment: I am using this API  GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?api-version=2021-04-01

in this api response i will get a resource name and location.

I need to store a location without duplication

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved in MCA billing account so use some combinations temporarily to avoid duplication until all accounts gets migrated towards MCA